# How can I boot ubuntu , if I downloaded it alongside windows 10?

Tags: boot

I downloaded Ubuntu alongside windows 10 with UEFI Gpt method. After installation I restarted computer, erased installation medium and pressed enter. But it is not showing any ubuntu selection options, it just boots windows and nothing else. What should I do?)

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Are you sure you installed it alongside Windows? Check if there is a partition that Windows cannot read or boot from a liveUSB and open gparted. If the main disk contains an ext4 partition then Ubuntu is probably installed. If there's no ext4 partition it surely isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Hardly anyone will help you because you didn’t write which manufacturer of that computer or laptop is. Because all manufacturers have a different way of setting up UEFI secure boot. If the installation went well, you should probably add Ubuntu to the "secure boot". As far as I know Lenovo automatically orders secure boot, Acer you have to manually order ...

Or it's a banal thing like a "boot order", an attempt in UEFI or BIOS under the boot section to change the boot order, and put ubuntu above windows.

If you fail then try to find some tutorial for your laptop brand + ubuntu install.